# Find the extreme values of $x^2+xy+y^2-27=0$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, multivariable-calculus, functions

I need to find the extreme values of $x^2+xy+y^2-27=0$. The hint is I need to use two points and use implicit function derivation. My thoughts were to pick up two points and then use the differentiation of this implicit function to get extrema by doing $g'(x)=0$. However, I don't even understand the hint, why would I pick two random points, and how do I know if I properly pick them?

Comment: Extreme values of... what? $y$? $x$? The equation $x^2+xy+y^2-27=0$ describes a curve, an ellipse to be more precise. Curves don't have extreme values. Functions defined on curves do. My guess is that you want extremal values of the $y$-coordinate, but please confirm.

Comment: Indeed. From my point of view it's asking for that y-coordinate extrema.

Comment: And, I think it likely that you have paraphrased the hint incorrectly. Assuming that we are looking for extremal values of $y$, you can, indeed, use implicit differentiation to find them. Implicit differentiation will give two (candidate) points. They are not random, your job is to solve for them. Then you need to compare them.

Comment: Right, i'll keep trying, thanks.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen How will I.D. work here? lets say I did $\frac{\partial}{\partial x} \text{ and }\frac{\partial}{\partial y}$ , I will get linear equations, solving them will give me the center of the conic...what next?

Comment: Differentiate implicitly w.r.t. $x$. That is, assume that $y$ is a function of $x$. You get the equation $$2x+y+x\frac{dy}{dx}+2y\frac{dy}{dx}=0.$$ Solve for $dy/dx$. On which points of the curve will you have $dy/dx=0$ (or undefined). Those are your candidate points.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen $dy/dx=\frac{-(2x+y)}{(2y+x)}$ if $dy/dx=0$, $2x+y=0$, if $dy/dx$ is undefined $x+2y=0$, if both are true the obtained (x,y) is the centre...I cannot obtain the candidate points.

Comment: Remember that the points must be on the curve. So solve for $x$ from $x+2y=0$ and substitute that to the original equation. You can equally well solve for $y$ and substitute that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find extremized value of $y$ in$$x^2+xy+y^2-27=0$$
A quadratic equation in $y$ is apparent  here:
$$y^2+(x)y+(x^2-27)=0$$

Using [Śrīdhara Ācāryya's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sridhara),
$$y=\frac{-x\pm\sqrt{x^2-4(x^2-27)}}{2 }\\y=\frac{-x\pm\sqrt{108-3x^2}}{2 }$$

Differentiating both sides and equating to zero, $$y'=-\frac{1}{2}\pm \frac{-3x}{2\sqrt{108-3x^2}}=0$$

The roots are at $x=\pm3$ which gives $y=\mp6$

---

The method suggested in the comment section by $\text{Jyrki Lahtonen}$ is a standard and swift way. It is depicted as follows:

Assume $y$ to be a function of $x$ and differentiate $x^2+xy+y^2-27=0$ w.r.t. $x$.

We get $$2x+y+x\frac{dy}{dx}+2y\frac{dy}{dx}=0 \\ \frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{-(2x+y)}{(2y+x)}$$

The extremisation occurs at critical points, i.e. when $\frac{dy}{dx}$ is zero or not defined, i.e.
$$\begin{align}
y&=-2x\\
y&=-\frac{x}{2}
\end{align}$$

Substituting $y$ in the primary equation, we get the values of $y=\pm3,\pm6$ which correspond to the extermisation in terms of $x$ and $y$ repectively.

[image]

Comment: Wow! I had no idea about that method, thank you :)

Comment: @FabrizioGambelín You are unaware of the quadratic formula? $$x=\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$$

Comment: Of course I know that one, but using x as a variable in it

Comment: @FabrizioGambelín yes for sure you can use it. It is treated just like any other constant like a, b or c

Comment: @FabrizioGambelín You can conclude the question. I have included both the methods, have a look.

Comment: I'm reading them and they are really clear. Thank you a lot!